# Web page rendering in IE7

Tags: xhtml, dtd

I am working on a site which is displayed properly in IE8 (when browser mode is IE8 and document mode is IE8 standards) and rest of the other browsers like chrome, firefox, etc. Except it is not diaplyed properly in IE7. I have heard of meta tags which allow users to force document mode to be displayed in a particular browser.

Comment: Nobody can help you since you haven't shown anything about the page that has the problem.

Comment: It works only downwards: you can't make IE7 behave like IE8. If it only were that easy!

Answer (score 0):

try adding the meta tag which will use Google Chrome Frame to render the page if chrome is installed in the machine.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">
```